# unix awk repeated pattern

Tags: unix, awk

I have the following variable. i want to search with pattern "/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/"

```
export str='16/02/02 11:29:22 INFO mortbay.log: State being saved: {"@class":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.FPTICopyState","timestamp":0,"state":"Running","name":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.FPTICopyState","id":"99c7cba7-d211-4845-97a1-c34168a91b22","subStates":{"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToLocalJob_fpti-raw-data-4_2016/02/02/10/":{"@class":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","timestamp":0,"state":"Stopped","name":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","id":"99034acb-cfad-41a0-89ed-e2731b1f82ec","subStates":null,"instanceState":"PostDone","window":"2016-02-02T10:00:00.000Z","datasetname":"fpti-raw-data-4","sourceDir":"/fpti/v2/hdfs_writer_4//2016/02/02/10/","localDir":"/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_4//2016/02/02/10//"},"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToLocalJob_fpti-raw-data_2016/02/02/10/":{"@class":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","timestamp":0,"state":"Stopped","name":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","id":"40325dec-0fe2-4025-8258-f896f957ddf0","subStates":null,"instanceState":"PostDone","window":"2016-02-02T10:00:00.000Z","datasetname":"fpti-raw-data","sourceDir":"/fpti/v2/hdfs_writer//2016/02/02/10/","localDir":"/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp//2016/02/02/10//"},"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToLocalJob_fpti-raw-data-1_2016/02/02/10/":{"@class":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","timestamp":0,"state":"Stopped","name":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","id":"5216f8c1-2cfa-4eac-a390-f4d2bcd6584f","subStates":{},"instanceState":"PostDone","window":"2016-02-02T10:00:00.000Z","datasetname":"fpti-raw-data-1","sourceDir":"/fpti/v2/hdfs_writer_1//2016/02/02/10/","localDir":"/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_1//2016/02/02/10//"},"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToLocalJob_fpti-raw-data-2_2016/02/02/10/":{"@class":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","timestamp":0,"state":"Stopped","name":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","id":"5fcd0b6e-3df9-4f82-a76f-bc8ff1493623","subStates":{},"instanceState":"PostDone","window":"2016-02-02T10:00:00.000Z","datasetname":"fpti-raw-data-2","sourceDir":"/fpti/v2/hdfs_writer_2//2016/02/02/10/","localDir":"/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_2//2016/02/02/10//"},"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToLocalJob_fpti-raw-data-3_2016/02/02/10/":{"@class":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","timestamp":0,"state":"Stopped","name":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","id":"6ec9223a-fcf0-447a-b9ae-2020e3232f6d","subStates":{},"instanceState":"PostDone","window":"2016-02-02T10:00:00.000Z","datasetname":"fpti-raw-data-3","sourceDir":"/fpti/v2/hdfs_writer_3//2016/02/02/10/","localDir":"/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_3//2016/02/02/10//"},"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToLocalJob_fpti-raw-data-5_2016/02/02/10/":{"@class":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","timestamp":0,"state":"Stopped","name":"com.paypal.fpti.hadoop.copy.CopyToJobState","id":"d123742c-8a55-4e25-bfa0-0a97f6ed25d7","subStates":{},"instanceState":"PostDone","window":"2016-02-02T10:00:00.000Z","datasetname":"fpti-raw-data-5","sourceDir":"/fpti/v2/hdfs_writer_5//2016/02/02/10/","localDir":"/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_5//2016/02/02/10//"}},"copystate":"CopyToLocalDone","start":"2016-02-02T11:21:24.678Z","end":null,"window":"2016-02-02T10:00:00.000Z","retryCount":0}'
```

I tried like below it gives the first occurence alone

```
[ggangadharan@phxbastion2 ~]$ echo $str | awk '{match($0, "/x/home[/,a-z,0-9,_]+*", a)}END{print a[0]}'
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_4//2016/02/02/10//
```

but i want output like below.

```
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_4//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_1//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_2//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_3//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_5//2016/02/02/10//
```

Can somebody help me how to use awk for this scenario?

thanks in advance

Comment: Awk processes each line, you'd have to do some significant splitting to parse the line and do multiple searches. You can use egrep for this particular problem, but more generally you can use other scripting tools to parse JSON. For this you could also `echo $str | egrep -o localDir[^,]* | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to hack this in awk, but you can safely use egrep here:

```
$ echo $str | egrep -o /x/home[/,a-z,0-9,_]+*
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_4//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_1//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_2//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_3//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_5//2016/02/02/10//
```

Comment: Thanks ferdy. it works

Generally if we grep it gives the entire line right??

can you please explain this functionality since i am new to unix scripting

Comment: Normally you'd use grep -E (or egrep, which is the same) if you search for patterns in a file with \n terminated lines and returns those. For the sake of -E a regex pattern can be used and will return every occurence of it in the current line, as we did here. I've added the -o (which means --only-matching) to just have the matching results of the regex. If you leave it out, the whole line of your log entry with your json will be shown; just as I said, normally you use grep to find lines which match a certain pattern. HTH

Comment: Thanks ferdy for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using "significant splitting" in AWK:

```
$ awk -v RS="\"" '/\/x\/home\/pp_dt_fpti_batch\/stampy_copy_orchestration\//' <<< "$str"
```

which gives

```
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_4//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_1//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_2//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_3//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_5//2016/02/02/10//
```

You specified `/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/` for your search pattern, so I used that.  If you want something different, use something different.

This separates input into records by a quote `"` (set `RS` to `"`, escaped in the shell).  Any record matching the regular expression is printed.  Input is given from the shell with the string `$str`.  Maybe this is more readable:

```
$ awk -v RS='"' '/regexp/' <<< "$str"
```

Comment: Great thing, though I'd recommend to use grep for this which makes it somewhat more readable for the yet less experienced awk user. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches using a JSON-aware command-line tool, here [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

In both cases we assume that the string of interest is embedded in the
JSON object contained in $str

(1) In the following, we simply pretty-print the JSON object and grep for
the string of interest in case it appears in a surprising spot.  Further trimming of the result can easily be done (e.g. using sed) as desired:

```
$ sed 's/^[^{]*//' <<< "$str" | jq '.[]' | fgrep /x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/
"localDir": "/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_4//2016/02/02/10//"
"localDir": "/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp//2016/02/02/10//"
"localDir": "/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_1//2016/02/02/10//"
"localDir": "/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_2//2016/02/02/10//"
"localDir": "/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_3//2016/02/02/10//"
"localDir": "/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_5//2016/02/02/10//"
```

(2) The following query is appropriate if we are only interested in a
match if it occurs in an object as a value corresponding to the key "localDir":

```
sed 's/^[^{]*//' <<< "$str" |
  jq -r '..
      | select(.localDir?)
      | .localDir
      | select(test("/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/"))'

/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_4//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_1//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_2//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_3//2016/02/02/10//
/x/home/pp_dt_fpti_batch/stampy_copy_orchestration/tmp_5//2016/02/02/10//
```